# Why am I getting a gap when trying to draw a string using a GraphicsPath object? C#/.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I'm trying to draw the path of some text characters on a 3D plane for printing on a 3D printer.  I'm getting gaps where the last line should be drawn.  I also tried drawing a rectangle using the AddRectangle command.  I ended up with a line.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Here are are the code snippets showing what I've written:

```
graphics_path1.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(50,50,50,50));
graphics_path1.AddString("Test text...", new FontFamily(workingFontObject.FONT.Name), (int)workingFontObject.FONT.Style, workingFontObject.FONT.Size, new Point(8, 2), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

RotateScaleOffsetGraphicsPath(graphics_path1, rotateAngle, RotateCenter, magnification, xyOffset);



    private void RotateScaleOffsetGraphicsPath(GraphicsPath workingGraphicsPath, float RotateAngle, PointF RotateCenter, float Magnification, PointF ROIOffset)
    {
        float Invert = (1.0f); //invert without any other modifications
        Matrix mm1 = new Matrix();  //Create a new matrix for transformations
        PointF bedCenter = new PointF(bedWidth/2,bedDepth/2);

        //mm1.RotateAt(RotateAngle, bedCenter, MatrixOrder.Append);//Rotate
        mm1.Translate(Invert*ROIOffset.X, Invert* ROIOffset.Y, MatrixOrder.Append);//set roi offset
        mm1.Scale(Magnification, Magnification, MatrixOrder.Append);//magnify, the 2 magnifications are x and y and can actually be different for a skewed growth

        //apply the transformation matrix on the graphical path
        workingGraphicsPath.Transform(mm1);
    }
```

> Blockquote

[image: Photo of gaps showing]

[image]

Comment: Does the same happen if you don't rotate?

Comment: Yes, I figured out the text (a loop wasn't closing).  As for the rectange/square, I'm completely lost.

Comment: Hm. Do you set any clipping? Can you influence the Line/Rectangle by moving it up a little? Do you draw in a Paint event?

Comment: I can't influence the rectangle.  I'm using a paint event.

Comment: Weird! Try to add another Rectangle (0,0,50,50) to see where it goes..!